# Which lifecycle event is the best place to register/ unregister a location listener?

Tags: android

I have a location listener that I want to work for as long as my activity is working.  This makes me think I should register it in onCreate and unregister it in onDestroy().

But! (As I understand it), if I unregister in onDestroy() and my application is killed, the location listeners remain and will just waste battery.

What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The typical place to do this is in onPause and onResume. Is there a reason why the activity needs to track location while it is in the background? Perhaps a bound service that delivers the data to the activity would be better.

Comment: Hi @Ted Hopp,    The listner doesn't really need to be working in the background when the app is not being used, but it needs to continue whenever the user goes into another acitivity on the same app (eg. the preference activity) ...